# Design Patterns to Handle Versioning

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, software-design

I am building software which references a DLL containing ~10 classes each representing a message. Each message contains fields that are specific to that message type. Every six months or so updates are made to each message type and I am looking to make the software flexible enough to smoothly handle these transitions. I would like to be able to select a version and a message type from a drop down menu in the GUI which would then reference the given version of that message type. I have a copy of the Gang of Four text and am trying to find a suitable solution to this task. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yon can take a look at the [Memento pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento). It could help you the dropdown in your UI client.

> to be able to select a version and a message type from a drop down menu in the GUI which would then reference the given version of that message type.

The last option can be the current .dll version. The Memento can be requested from the source object when it needs to checkpoint the source object's state. The client is the "care-taker" of the Memento, but only the source object can store and retrieve information from the Memento (the Memento is "opaque" to the client and all other objects). If the client subsequently needs to "rollback" the source object's state, it hands the Memento back to the source object for reinstatement. It goes naturally with [Command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command).

Answer (score 2):

You can use command pattern for the rollback part as mentioned above. 
Then you can use POJOs for the messages. Since the POJO features will change you can use Adapter or Decorator pattern to make the changes in the POJO, or you can directly change the POJO class, or you can extend the POJO classes into new POJO classes. And rest you can follow as mentioned by @ekostadinov.